# Is there a way to create a Windows power plan with C#?

Tags: c#, performance, winforms

I've been working on a small Windows Forms based program (in C#) and I just started developing around 3 weeks ago. I'm not sure if this is possible through C# but I figure I'd ask in case anyone has a solution. I'm also not great at explaining things, so if you have any other questions, I'll be glad to answer them!

So, my goal is to create a function that allows me to define power plan settings (via GUID), create a power plan, and apply it for the user. I'm not sure how to go about this however, as CMD commands don't work in my use case as I want to create a power plan, not import one. I also looked at solutions that used powrprof.dll but that only changed default settings in the registry. I've also looked at other posts on StackOverflow related to this topic but have only found ways to import a power plan, not create one.

I'm not sure where to look and I've only hit dead-ends when it comes to this topic. If you have any solutions, I'm open to hearing them, regardless of the difficulty! Thank you and I hope you all have a wonderful day!

Comment: Take a look at this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d14545ad-b259-498e-92d4-311b3b45de83/create-new-power-scheme-from-c?forum=csharplanguage).

Comment: @GellioGao I'll take a look at this thread, thank you!